# How to make google search dynamic pages of my site

Tags: php

I am planning an informational site on php with mysql.
I have read about google sitemap and webmaster tools.

What i did not understand is will google be able to index dynamic pages of my site using any of these tools.

For example if i have URLs like    www.domain.com/articles.php?articleid=103

Obviously this page will be having same title and same meta information always but the content will change according to articleid. So how google will come to know about the article on the page to display in search.

Is there some way that i can get google rankings for these pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could alternatively make the url [SEO](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=seo%20tips) friendly with [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) `www.domain.com/articles/103`

```
RewriteRule ^articles/(.*)$ articles.php?articleid=$1 [L]
```

I do suggest you give each individual page relevant meta tags no more then 80 chars and dont place the article content within a `table` tag as [googles placement algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Panda) is strict, random non related links will also do harm to the rank.

Comment: How can i write specific meta tags for the pages as content will be coming from database. Also can you provide some more details about SEO friendly URL

Comment: Well you could get the description tag of the page by using `substr()` on the article content & for the meta tags, either add them as you insert the article in a separate column within the db or pass the content through a user function to strip out common words & implode with a separator. A simple `SEO` google search will yeald more info then I could explain here.

Answer (score 2):

A URL is a URL, Google doesn't give up when it sees a question mark in one (although excessive parameters may get ignored, but you only have one). All you need is a link to a page.

Answer (score 1):

You have to link to the page for Google to notice it. And the more links you have the higher up in Google's result list your page will get. A smart thing to do is to find a page where you can link to all of your pages. This way Google will find them and give them a higher ranking than if you only link to them once.