# PHP Sudirectory to get request

Tags: php, get, subdirectory

Is there a way to redirect from a subdirectory on a webserver to a get request in php?  What I would like is for visitors to be able to visit a subdirectory like:  www.example.com/subdirectory, and have this redirected to or treated as www.example.com/page.php?id=subdirectory ...

I could of course create a script that writes a php file to the given subdirectory with something like: `header("www.example.com/page.php?id=subdirectory");`  but is there a way to do this without having to create new files for each new link? thanks.

Comment: If you use apache, a  mod rewrite rule can do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make google search dynamic pages of my site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201186/how-to-make-google-search-dynamic-pages-of-my-site)